# AttributeError: type object 'AnimationTransition' has no attribute 'in:out_expo'

Tags: python, kivy

Buenas quería consultar si alguno sabe resolver el error " AttributeError: type object 'AnimationTransition' has no attribute 'in:out_expo'" estoy trabajando en una aplicación en Kivy pero me aparece eso cuando ajusto la ventana.

[image: Ejemplo de python]

[image: Ejemplo de Kivy]

[image: Error]

A si se sería el ejemplo

Comment: Lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5493/158880. Sin un ejemplo minimo, completo y verificable, no podemos solucionar el error.

Comment: Para resolverlo lo primero es revisar que le estés pasando un objeto del tipo adecuado.